# How to get all possible combinations of an array but with certain elements only changing (in Javascript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, binary, combinations, permutation

Hi can anyone please help me. I want to be able to generate all possible combinations of the array but only certain elements will be changing given two possible numbers to choose from. Their position is important too.

For example: let arr = [1,2,3, (4 or 5), (6 or 7), (8 or 9)]

I want to generate 
1,2,3,4,6,8 
1,2,3,4,6,9 
1,2,3,4,7,8 
. 
. 
. 
. 
This goes on until 1,2,3,5,7,9

I know it is very similar to binary numbers, I just don't know how to go about it and also the array may change in size so it can lead to a lot of options and possible outcomes.

Please. Someone help.

Edit: clarified the combinations I want to generate

Comment: but there should be 8 (sorry, didn't read it right) possibilities, not 3 ... right? you'll want some loops maybe 4 ... but it could be done with less

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot to add that it goes on. Wouldn't there be only 8 possibilities because of 2^3? The first 3 elements remain constant.

Comment: yeah, 8 - re-read the question :p

Comment: so, something like `const result = Array.from({length:8}, (_, n) => [1,2,3,[4,5][+!!(n&4)],[6,7][+!!(n&2)],[8,9][+!!(n&1)]])`

Comment: oh wow! this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much!!! I'll look into it more as I don't really understand what "+!!" means

Comment: the `!!` converts the result of the & operator to false if 0, and to true if not 0, then the `+` converts false to 0 and true to 1 to get an index of 0 or 1 - there is other ways to do it though - `const result = Array.from({length:8}, (_, n) => [1,2,3,[4,2,1][4,5][(n&4)>>2],[6,7][(n&2)>>1],[8,9][(n&1)]])` for example

Comment: The general idea you're looking for is the "cartesian product" of multiple arrays; see the answers to the linked question.  If you use the code there here it gives you [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoGzlW).

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you!! I was really having a hard time and both of you are so helpful!